# Pm2 monit shows heap usage is almost 100%. Is this ok?

Tags: node.js, pm2

I was watching `pm2 monit`.

My server process `Mem` coloured red.

[image]

I've checked my metrix
[image]

**I need help understanding heap usage.**.
Almost 100%?
While heap size is only 30Mib ?

I allowed 2GB of memory to be used when running node.js.

Also, I checked the memory resources of the server, there was enough free memory.

What does this Usage mean?

And why is my mem painted red?.

Comment: Would you rather it used 6% of 2GB? A low heap size and a high utilization means it is running efficiently. A high heap size and low utilization means it's not releasing memory it isn't using.

Comment: @tadman UMMM!!!! so it should not be 1.8GB ? even though i allowed 2GB maximum they try to allocate more smaller size? for better optimize is this correct ?

Comment: You're *limiting* memory usage to 2GB. You're not forcing it to use that much out of the gate. In general, Node processes try and shed any allocations no longer needed, as in after garbage collection, to keep memory usage down.

Comment: @tadman Thank you! Maybe this question is too simplistic, but it was new territory for me.

Comment: If you're used to Java, where it stubbornly hangs on to as much memory as it can, Node's behaviour might seem unfamiliar.